# listView items with group

Tags: android, listview

I have an `ListView` with `BaseAdapter` now I just make some listener to item when I click on item I show some hidden view in item.

Every time I click on some item, I show the hidden view or hide them if views  are visible. But the problem I face is that I want to hide the other visible item when the I show a new item.

Here I click on some item and its shows the message date and detail:

[image: screenshot 1]

Now when I click on other items, I want to hide the first one and show the second, like this:

[image: screenshot 2]

But here in my code when I click on other item its of course will not hide the previous view. How can I do this trick ?

Comment: @TheOneWhoMade and KlingKlang If you're going to edit a post, take the time to do it right. Neither of these were meaningful edits.

Comment: @Sam please edit question for show image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply keep a reference to the last view that was clicked, let's call it `mLastViewShown`;

```
new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (mLastViewShown != null)
            hideDetails();
        mLastViewShown = view;

        showDetails();
    }
};
```

Now you have a variable to hide the details from the last user click.

Comment: i will try this  and return :D

Answer (score 0):

So you want to hide all item's additional field when you click on some other item. In addition to this you also want to toggle visibility of an item's additional view on click on same item.
Here is your main activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private List<ListData> list=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //get the toolbar instance

    handleListClick();
    list.add(new ListData("George","Surgeon"));
    list.add(new ListData("Nancy","Dentist"));
    list.add(new ListData("Henry","Nurse"));

}

private void handleListClick() {
    ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final CustomBaseAdapter customBaseAdapter=new CustomBaseAdapter(this,list);
    listView.setAdapter(customBaseAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            customBaseAdapter.setCurrentSelected(position);
            customBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
   }
 }
```

Here is your custom base adapter:

```
    public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private  List<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
    private  LayoutInflater inflater;
    private  Context context;
    private int previousSelected=-1;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<ListData> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
   }

    public void setCurrentSelected(int currentSelected){
    if(previousSelected==currentSelected)
        previousSelected=-1;
    else
        previousSelected=currentSelected;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListData getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
    }

     @Override
     public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
     }

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     MyViewHolder mViewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
        mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
    } else {
        mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ListData currentListData = getItem(position);

     mViewHolder.tvMain.setText(currentListData.getMainText());
     if(previousSelected==position){
        mViewHolder.tvAdditional.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);

   mViewHolder.tvAdditional.setText(currentListData.getAdditionalText());
    }else{
        mViewHolder.tvAdditional.setVisibility(TextView.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
    }

     private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView tvMain, tvAdditional;


    public MyViewHolder(View item) {
        tvMain = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        tvAdditional = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.additional_text);

      }
    }
 }
```

Here is your ListData:

```
  public class ListData {
   private String mainText;
   private String additionalText;

    public ListData(String mainText, String additionalText) {
    this.mainText = mainText;
    this.additionalText = additionalText;
    }

    public String getMainText() {
    return mainText;
    }

   public void setMainText(String mainText) {
    this.mainText = mainText;
   }

   public String getAdditionalText() {
    return additionalText;
   }

  public void setAdditionalText(String additionalText) {
    this.additionalText = additionalText;
  }
 }
```

Here is your row_item.xml layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/additional_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is activity_main.xml layout file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.dexter.stackoverflow.MainActivity">


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```